# Windows 10: Connect to WiFi network using keyboard only

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the quickest way to connect to a WiFi network (one that my computer knows already but is not connected to at the moment) in Windows 10 using keyboard only?

What I tried:

1. Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to focus taskbar, then use arrows to get to "WiFi Popup". In the "WiFi Popup", use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle focus. However the TAB is completely skipping the part of window in which individual WiFi networks are listed. So, it doesn't work.
2. Going through settings. Very long and annoying process using keyboard only.

Questions:

1. What is the quickest way of doing this in Windows 10 without any 3rd party app?
2. What 3rd party app can help me with this?

Comment: About not being able to choose the WiFi entry with keyboard: I tried; you are right; it sucks. Be sure to send a feedback about it to Microsoft using the Feedback Hub app.

Comment: If you literally do not have access to a mouse, you can do Roman Ludwig's solution by opening a Command Prompt by doing `Windows Key + R` then typing `cmd` and then hitting `Enter`. Alternatively, you can do `Windows Key + X` and then pressing `C`. Either of these methods opens the command line..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To connect to a Wifi network with known name xyz you can use the command-line:

```
netsh wlan connect name="xyz"
```

and to disconnect use:

```
netsh wlan disconnect
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way is to place WiFi tile in the top left corner in action center and then press:

<kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open action center

<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> - to cycle to WiFi tile

<kbd>Space</kbd> - to enable/disable

Comment: On Windows 10 `20H2` I have to press tab 3 times to get to WIFI. Then I can press `space` or `return`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shortcut on the desktop then assign that shortcut to a specific key combination.

- Step 1: Right click on desktop and click New > Shortcut
- Step 2: Type "%windir%\explorer.exe %LocalAppData%\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Indexed\Settings\en-US\AAA_SettingsPageNetworkWiFi.settingcontent-ms"
- Step 3: Name the shortcut and close
- Step 4: Right click the shortcut and go properties > Shortcut > Advanced and tick run as admin
- Step 5: In the shortcut properties, add a shortcut Key

This will open the window showing all the networks. It's close (not sure if close enough)

Comment: On Version 1803 (build 17134.345) the string in "Step 2" does **not** open WiFi settings. I think making a shortcut to a script using "netsh wlan" would be a more reliable solution. kr

Answer (score 2):

> Hit Win+B to focus taskbar, then use arrows to get to "WiFi Popup".

Use down arrow to select one of the available wifi networks. Press enter to get details of wifi network selected, then use tab to select connect and hit enter.

Comment: This is the right answer for me, no add ons, no shell required.... except it doesn't work for me. Win+B focuses the taskbar and I can choose between the tasks.... but WIFI and many others won't bring up the larger menu with Enter on them (or Space... can't think of anything else that might work). Sigh Microsoft.

Comment: Win+A or Win+B, which one gets you earlier to the point?

Answer (score 1):

I regularly connect to several WiFi networks, which I've set to "Connect automatically". So all I wanted to do was make shortcuts to turn my WiFi adapter on and off, without having to specify a certain network.

If you've set the network(s) you use to "Connect automatically", here's how you can make simple "Enable/Disable WiFi" shortcuts, as I did:

First, to create a shortcut that turns your WiFi **ON**:

1. At a command prompt, type this and press Enter: *netsh interface show interface*
2. Note the "Interface Name" that appears. Mine was called simply *Wi-Fi*, so that's the name I'll use here.
3. Right-click your desktop > New > Shortcut
4. In the box that appears, type this in the "Type location of the item" box:

   *C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe interface set interface Wi-Fi enable*

   (If your Interface Name isn't "Wi-Fi", type THAT name here instead.)
5. Click Next. When prompted, type a name for the shortcut, like "Enable WiFi" (without the quotes).
6. Right-click the new shortcut, then click Properties. In the "Shortcut key" box, type the key combination you want to use to turn your WiFi **ON**. (I used Ctrl+Shift+F11.)
7. Click the "Advanced" button. Select the "Run as Administrator" checkbox, then click OK > OK to close the dialog boxes.

To create a shortcut that turns your WiFi **OFF**:

1. Right-click your new shortcut and click Copy. A copy of the shortcut appears.
2. Right-click the copy you just made, then click Properties.
3. In the dialog box that appears, be sure the "Shortcut" tab is selected.
4. In the "Target" box, change "enable" to "disable" (without quotes). The command should now say:

   *C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe interface set interface Wi-Fi disable*
5. In the "Shortcut key" box, type the key combination you want to use to turn your WiFi **OFF**. (I used Ctrl+Shift+F12.)
6. On the General tab, change the shortcut's name (e.g. "Disable WiFi").
7. Click OK to close the dialog box.

**Notes:**

• When you run the "Enable" shortcut, it takes a moment for your adapter to connect to the network you've set to "Connect automatically"—so don't worry if the WiFi icon doesn't change immediately.

• To help me remember the keys I gave my shortcuts, I added them to the shortcuts' names—my shortcuts are called:

*Enable WiFi (Ctrl+Shift+F11)*

and

*Disable WiFi (Ctrl+Shift+F12)*

BTW, David, I'm sorry you didn't like my previous comment, where I explained why these solutions didn't work for me (too network-specific) and what I wanted to do. I wasn't trying to be impertinent—I just hoped someone might see what I wanted to do, and post a more specific solution. I found it myself, as it turned out, so I'm glad to share. (I'm a technical writer.) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 desktop shortcuts with the following commands to toggle Wifi.

1. Right-click on the desktop.
2. Go to **New** > **Shortcut**.
3. For the location, enter "*netsh wlan disconnect*."
4. Click **Next** and then click **Finish**. This creates a link on the desktop.
5. Right-click the link and go to the Shortcut tab.
6. Create a keyboard shortcut using the keys.
7. (Optional) Go to the **General** tab and select the **Hidden** checkbox to hide the shortcut.

You can do the same with the "*netsh wlan connect name="Wifi network name*" command to turn wifi on.